# Sign in link removed after moving search inside navigation container

Tags: layout, frontend, search, navigation

I am moving search inside the navigation container using this code:

```
<move element="top.search" destination="catalog.topnav" before="-"/>
```

a 
in the default.xml file, 
but when I moving search inside navigation sign the in the link has been removed, anybody they have the solution for this.

Comment: Try `php bin/magento cache:flush` and open in private browser window. sometimes it takes time to appear because of JS or cache.

Comment: I have tried the same code in Magento 2 default theme and its working for me.

Comment: I have tried as you suggested but still facing same issue

Comment: i am trying in my child theme based on luma.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me

```
<move element="top.search" destination="catalog.topnav" after="-" />
```

It has moved the search div inside on `nav`.

Comment: yes it has moved but after moving search its removing sign in link.